# How to use variable(i) from a for loop in regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find matches in pandas text column  as per my pattern, any word between text: and , . Example:

| column | text |
| --- | --- |
| text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh, | xyzs |

```
try:
    df['text']=df['column'].str.extract(r'text:(.+?),')
except AttributeError:
    flange ['text'] =np.nan
```

I want to use a for loop to dynamically changing the regex starting pettern. Example replace text to line then sentence.

```
for i in ['text','line','sentence']:
    df[i] = df['column'].str.extract(r'i:(.+?),')    # This is not working trying to replace text: to i:
```

Output should be :

| column | text | line | sentence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh, | xyzs | yzds | dhfjdh |

Answer (score 1):

You can capture both the pre- and post- separator, then `pivot`:

```
out = (df['column']
 .str.extractall(r'([^,:]+):([^,:]+)')
 .droplevel(1)
 .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
 #.reindex(list_of_cols, axis=1)  # if needed reindex with a list of wanted terms
)
```

*NB. if you want specific prefixes, you can either incorporate them in the regex (e.g., `r'(text|line):([^,:]+)'`), and/or `reindex` afterwards.*

output:

```
0  line sentence  text
0  yzds   dhfjdh  xyzs
1  efgh     ijkl  abcd
```

used input:

```
                                column
0  text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh
1    line:efgh,text:abcd,sentence:ijkl
```

You can also `join` the original dataframe:

```
df.join(out)
```

output:

```
                                column  line sentence  text
0  text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh  yzds   dhfjdh  xyzs
1    line:efgh,text:abcd,sentence:ijkl  efgh     ijkl  abcd
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.apply(
            lambda x: {
                (v := s.split(":"))[0]: v[1]
                for s in map(str.strip, x["column"].split(","))
                if s != ""
            },
            axis=1,
        ).apply(pd.Series),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                 column  text  line sentence
0  text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh,  xyzs  yzds   dhfjdh
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, using f-strings:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh,',
                              'text:abc,sentence:def,line:xyz12345,',
                              'sentence:abcdef,line:4ta12,text:abc,']})
for i in ['text','line','sentence']:
    df[i] = df['column'].str.extract(fr'\b{i}:([^,]+)')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                 column  text      line sentence
0  text:xyzs,line:yzds,sentence:dhfjdh,  xyzs      yzds   dhfjdh
1  text:abc,sentence:def,line:xyz12345,   abc  xyz12345      def
2  sentence:abcdef,line:4ta12,text:abc,   abc     4ta12   abcdef
```